# S3 Replication - destination files deleted replication behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

With S3 replication, if a previously replicated file is deleted in the destination bucket, is the default behaviour that the file will be re-copied? I assume this is the case and if so, is there any way to change this behaviour so files are only ever replicated once?

Comment: posted a solution which tells why rereplication will not takes place once object is replicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if a previously replicated file is deleted in the destination bucket, is the default behaviour that the file will be re-copied

**NO, it wont be recopied** because according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) `"By default, replication only supports copying new Amazon S3 objects after it is enabled."`

So literally s3 sees it as an existing object which is already replicated to destination no matter whether it is deleted in destination or not, it won't replicate AGAIN!

Comment: Thanks. But I think that section of the docs is just stating that any files in the source bucket prior to replication being enabled won't be replicated. I was wondering if there's some way to replicate a file once then ignore it even if it no longer exists in the destination bucket.

Comment: `"By default, replication only supports copying new Amazon S3 objects after it is enabled."` this line is coming from docs, which means once replication is enabled after that only new objects will be replicated, since the object which is deleted in destination is already replicated and is seen as old one in source bucket that is why it wont be replicated again.i have personally tried this scenario and with conviction i can say s3 doesn't replicate again, by default it is being replicated exactly once